# gatsby build is not running on jenkins shows error "error Plugin gatsby-source-strapi returned an error"

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, gatsby, strapi

I had a CICD pipeline in jenkins which initially connects with strapi then it will do the gatsby build. But in jenkins it shows error `Plugin gatsby-source-strapi returned an error` and `Request failed with status code 500`. My jenkins was running on aws server instance. But when I tried this CICD build in my localhost jenkins it is working properly.

What may be issue with my jenkins.

Or do I need to change gatsby-config.js?

My jenkins error message

```
error Plugin gatsby-source-strapi returned an error

[0m
[0m  [0m[97m[41mError[0m[37m[41m:[0m[37m[41m [0m[97m[41mRequest failed with status code 500[0m
[0m  [0m
[0m  [0m[90m-[0m [0m[93mcreateError.js[0m[90m:[0m[93m16[0m[37m [0m[37mcreateError[0m
[0m  [0m  [0m[90m[SH_Website_CI_CD]/[axios]/lib/core/createError.js:16:15[0m
[0m  [0m
[0m  [0m[90m-[0m [0m[93msettle.js[0m[90m:[0m[93m18[0m[37m [0m[37msettle[0m
[0m  [0m  [0m[90m[SH_Website_CI_CD]/[axios]/lib/core/settle.js:18:12[0m
[0m  [0m
[0m  [0m[90m-[0m [0m[93mhttp.js[0m[90m:[0m[93m201[0m[37m [0m[37mIncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd[0m
[0m  [0m  [0m[90m[SH_Website_CI_CD]/[axios]/lib/adapters/http.js:201:11[0m
[0m  [0m
[0m  [0m[90m-[0m [0m[93mnext_tick.js[0m[90m:[0m[93m63[0m[37m [0m[37mprocess._tickCallback[0m
[0m  [0m  [0m[90minternal/process/next_tick.js:63:19[0m
[0m  [0m
[0m
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! gatsby-starter-default@0.1.0 cdnBuild: `NODE_ENV=cdn gatsby build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the gatsby-starter-default@0.1.0 cdnBuild script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /var/lib/jenkins/.npm/_logs/2019-05-30T05_40_12_432Z-debug.log
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] echo
ERROR - hudson.AbortException: script returned exit code 1
```

Any help

Thank you

Comment: Could you check if your jenkins job can access the strapi endpoint?

Comment: @Geku no I did not check that. Can you say how to check it. Both my strapi and gatsby are running on same server.

Comment: @Geku And I am running my strapi with pm2. In my localhost jenkins server it is working properly, but in server only it is not working.

Comment: Tell me which parameters you have in the configuration of the gatsby-strapi plugin. Check which url is inside the apiURL parameter and see if it's correctly pointing to the port where your strapi is located. If you think that the config is ok and you cannot make it work, feel free to send me a "prototype" of what you have or the repo itself and i'll check what's wrong there. Cheers!

Comment: @Geku I solved this issue. You are right.

Comment: Good to know, have fun!